# Can't use a negative number in named parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, named-parameters

I'm using Scala 2.11.2.

If I have this Fraction class:

```
case class Fraction(numerator: Int, denominator: Int) {}
```

Then this gives an error:

```
val f = new Fraction(numerator=-1, denominator=2)
```

But this is not:

```
val f = new Fraction(-1, denominator=2)
```

The error message is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- not found: value 
 numerator
- not found: value 
 numerator
```

I tried to use negative numbers in other snippets with the same result, but the documentation doesn't mentions that this is not possible.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need a space between the `=` and the `-`, or you can wrap the -1 in parentheses, otherwise the compiler gets confused. This is because `=-` is a valid method name, so the compiler cannot tell whether you are assigning a value to a named parameter, or making a method call.

so this gives an error:

```
val f = Fraction(numerator=-1, denominator=2)
```

but this is OK:

```
val f = Fraction(numerator = -1, denominator = 2)
```

and so is this:

```
val f = Fraction(numerator=(-1), denominator=2)
```

Comment: Also `new` keyword is not required. Its a case class.

Comment: `numerator= -1` should be enough

Comment: Yes, that's fine too - just need to separate the `=` and `-`

Comment: `-Xprint:parser` helps diagnose it. Also, not sure this isn't a parser bug or room for improvement. SIP-1 just says it has the form `x = expr`, "same syntax as variable assignments." Probably asking too much to parse twice; the way it must try both named arg and assignment.